# Does outer disposable dispose the inner disposable automatically in rxjava?

Tags: android, rx-java2

I have a situation like this:

```
outerDisposable = Observable.intervalRange(1,maxCount,initialDelay,interval,TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS,AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .subscribe(time ->

{
    if (time == maxCount) {
        liveData.setValue("Event"));
        innerDisposable = Completable.complete()
                .delay(60000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .doOnComplete(() -> liveData.postValue("Event"))
                .subscribe();
    } else {
        liveData.setValue("Event");
    }
});
```

My question is, If I dispose the `outerDisposable` then should the `innerDisposable` be automatically disposed or I have to dispose both disposable each time separately?

Comment: You can check with `innerDisposable.isDisposed` after disposing the outer one.

Comment: I know that, but want to know what exactly happen under the hood in this case.

Comment: obervable will be there in memory holding view references and occupying memory.

Comment: I think having an inner subscription is a bad practice. I would rather try to use one single Observable and chain the operations.

Comment: How would your outer disposable know about your inner disposable - it makes no programming sence in general. Also calling `subscribe()` inside a `subscribe()` is discouraged. Use composition and continuation schemes such as `concatMap`/`flatMap`.